# Nozzle cleaning tool broken inside nozzle

Tags: nozzle, cleaning

Recently I opened up my printer (PowerSpec Duplicator i3 Mini V2)to clean the nozzle (it comes with the little tool to get tiny bits of filament out of the nozzle). Well, I was using that and when I pulled it out I discovered the tool broke inside the nozzle. Filament is still coming out but obviously not properly. Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: please share a photo of th enozzle so we can tell you waht design of replacement nozzle you need.

Comment: Time for a new nozzle.

Answer (score 4):

Your best fix is to get a replacement nozzle. Nozzles are relatively cheap. Having and replacing them on a regular basis is a good thing. Replacement can help you maintain proper printing. You can probably get the cleaning tool out of the old nozzle, but most likely you'll damage it further, making it nearly useless.